# How to calculate the complexity of the Algorithm?

Tags: time-complexity

I have to calculate the complexity of this algorithm,I tried to solve it and found the answer to be O(nlogn). Is it correct ? If not please explain.

```
for (i=5; i<n/2; i+=5) 
{
     for (j=1; j<n; j*=4)
          op;

     x = 3*n;
     while(x > 6) 
          {op;  x--;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Katrina, In this example we've got an O (n*log(n))
`

```
for (int i= 0; i < N; i++) {
       c= i;
       while (c > 0) {
         c= c/2
       }
     }
```

How ever you have another for that includes this both bucles.
Im not quite sure to understand the way it works the algorithm but an standard way considering an another for bucle, should be O(n*n*log n

```
for (int j= 0; i < N); j++) { --> O(n)
   for (int i= 0; i < N; i++) { O(n)
       c= i;
       while (c > 0) { O(logn)
         c= c/2        O(1)
       }
     }
  } ?
```

Aftermath in this standard algorithm would be O(n) * O(n) * O(logn) * O(1)

So, I think you forgot to include another O(n)
)
Hope it helps

Comment: So it should be for (i=5; i<n/2; i+=5) // O(n)
{
     for (j=1; j<n; j*=4)// O(logn)
          op;

     x = 3*n;
     while(x > 6)//  O(n)
          {op;  x--;}
}    O(n^2 log(n))

Answer (score 0):

Let's count the number of iterations in each loop.

The outermost loop `for (i=5; i<n/2; i+=5)` steps through all values between `5` and `n / 2` in steps of `5`. It will, thus, require *approximately* `n / 10 - 1` iterations.

There are two inner loops. Let's consider the first one: `for (j=1; j<n; j*=4)`. This steps through all values of the form `4^x` between `1` and `n` for integers of `x`. The lowest value of `x` for this to be true is `0`, and the highest value is the `x` that fulfills `4^x < n` -- i.e., the integer closest to `log_4(n)`. Thus, labelling the iterations by `x`, we have iterations `0, 1, ..., log_4(n)`. In other words, we've approximately `log_4(n) + 1` iterations for this loop.

Now consider the second inner loop. It steps through all values from `3 * n` down to `7`. Thus the number of iterations are approximately `3 n - 6`.

All other operations have constant run time and can therefore be ignored.

How do we put this together? The two inner loops are run sequentially (i.e., they are not nested) so the run time for both of them together is simply the sum:

```
(log_4(n) + 1) + (3 n - 6) = 3 n + log_4(n) - 5.
```

The outer loop and the two inner loops are, however, nested. For every iteration of the outer loop, both the inner ones are run. Therefore we multiply the number of iterations of the outer with the total of the inner:

```
(n / 10 - 1) * (3 n + log_4(n) - 5) =
       = 3 n^2 / 10 + n log_4(n) / 10 - 7 n / 2 - log_4(n) + 5.
```

Finally, complexity is often expressed in Big-O notation -- that is, we're only interested in the order of the run time. This means two things. First, we can ignore all constant factors in all terms. For example, `O(3 n^2 / 10)` becomes just `O(n^2)`. Thereby we have:

```
O(3 n^2 / 10 + n log_4(n) / 10 - 7 n / 2 - log_4(n) + 5) =
       = O(n^2 + n log_4(n) - n - log_4(n) + 1).
```

Second, we can ignore all terms that have a lower order than the term with the highest order. For example, `n` is of an higher order than `1` so we have `O(n + 1) = O(n)`. Thereby we have:

```
O(n^2 + n log_4(n) - n - log_4(n) + 1) = O(n^2).
```

Finally, we have the answer. The complexity of the algorithm your code describes is `O(n^2)`.

(In practice, one would never calculate the (approximate) number of iterations as we did here. The simplification we did in the last step can be done earlier which makes the calculations much easier.)

Answer (score 0):

As Fredrik mentioned, time complexity of first and third loops are `O(n)`. an time for second loop is `O(log(n))`.

> So complexity of following algorithm is `O(n^2)`.

```
for (i=5; i<n/2; i+=5) 
{
 for (j=1; j<n; j*=4)
      op;

 x = 3*n;
 while(x > 6) 
      {op;  x--;}
}
```

> Note that complexity of following algorithm is `O(n^2*log(n))` which is not same with above algorithm.

```
for (i=5; i<n/2; i+=5) 
{
 for (j=1; j<n; j*=4)
  {
   op;
   x = 3*n;
   while(x > 6) 
      {op;  x--;}
  }
}
```